# How to get metrics data from aws cloudwatch to csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

i have been working on project, and i want to export metrics data from cloudwatch like CPU Utilization and Network Out data, is there any way to get that data? and convert it to csv?

Answer (score 29):

### Export CloudWatch Metrics

You can't do it directly but following is the step by step instructions:

### Pre Reqs

1. AWS CLI (Command Line Interface) from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)
2. **jq** is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

### How to export

Use the following CLI:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
--namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization 
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
--statistics Average 
--start-time 2020-03-01T00:00:00 
--end-time 2020-03-31T23:59:00 
--period 3600
--region us-east-1
```

Valid options for **--metric-name** depend on the **--name-space** parameter. For AWS/EC2, the full list can be seen by running the following CLI command:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "AWS/EC2"
```

Valid options for **--statistics** are:

```
SampleCount
Average
Sum
Minimum
Maximum
```

**--start-time** and **--end-time** specify the range.

**--period** The granularity, in seconds, of the returned data points.

**--region** The region where the CloudWatch metric is being meatured (us-east-1, us-west-2 etc.)

Data output will look something like the following:

```
{
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": []
}
```

To convert it to CSV we will use **jq**. For this you have two options:

### Option 1

Pipe all the aws cli output to jq:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
--namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization 
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
--statistics Average 
--start-time 2020-03-01T00:00:00 
--end-time 2020-03-31T23:59:00 
--period 3600
--region us-east-1
| jq -r '.Datapoints[] | [.Timestamp, .Minimum, .Unit] | @csv'
```

### Option 2

Export the data to JSON:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
--namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization 
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
--statistics Average 
--start-time 2020-03-01T00:00:00 
--end-time 2020-03-31T23:59:00 
--period 3600
--region us-east-1 >> data.json
```

Use jq to read the json to csv:

```
jq -r '.Datapoints[] | [.Timestamp, .Minimum, .Unit] | @csv' data.json
```

### Output

Here is how the output will look like:

```
"2020-03-24T11:00:00Z",0.327868852454245,"Percent"
"2020-03-11T21:00:00Z",0.327868852454245,"Percent"
"2020-03-15T04:00:00Z",0.322580645156596,"Percent"
"2020-03-27T18:00:00Z",0.327868852478101,"Percent"
```

Comment: hi @mmansoor, you save my live today :)

in your examples say: [.Timestamp, .Minimum, .Unit] but is [.Timestamp, .Average, .Unit]

Comment: FYI your `jq` download link is the same as your AWS one. Perhaps you wanted https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ ?

Comment: @Offlein I fixed the jq link

Comment: Is there a way to get chronologically ordered data?
@mmansoor

Answer (score 6):

There is no **in-built capability** to export Amazon CloudWatch metrics to CSV.

There are API calls available to extract metrics, but you would need to write a program to call the API, receive the metrics and store it in a suitable format.

There are projects available that can assist with this, such as:

- [mogproject/cloudwatch-dump: Just dump all the CloudWatch metrics.](https://github.com/mogproject/cloudwatch-dump)
- [AWS – CloudWatch – DataExtractor – API | vMan](https://vman.ch/aws-cloudwatch-dataextractor-api/)
- [romgapuz/awsmetric2csv: AWS Metric to CSV is a Python command-line utility to extract CloudWatch metric data from an AWS resources (e.g. EC2, RDS) and save to a CSV file.](https://github.com/romgapuz/awsmetric2csv)

If you are looking for these types of tools, make sure they refer to CloudWatch **metrics**, not **CloudWatch Logs** (which is something different).

Answer (score 1):

You can now download the metrics directly from AWS Metrics dashboard in the .csv file format. As shown in the image in order to download the metrics from AWS, you need to go the `CloudWatch dashboard` and click on the `Metrics` in the left navigation bar and then select the metric you want to download. Now click on the `Actions` drop-down button and select `Download as .csv`

[image: Screen shot of AWS CloudWatch dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out official Prometheus [cloudwatch_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter)

Answer (score 0):

If the csv exporting is a routine work, you can try [categraf cloudwatch plugin](https://github.com/flashcatcloud/categraf/tree/main/inputs/cloudwatch) . It can easily export cloud-watch metrics to your Prometheus then you can visualize data using grafana and export to csv.

And further more, you can also try [nightingale project](https://github.com/ccfos/nightingale) which can be an alternative of prometheus&grafana.